# MYSQL how to ensure that one query is ran right after another

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, locking

I have problems with concurrent connections. How do i ensure that one query in ran just after another, without queries from another connections coming in between. I'll probably need some kind of locking, but what kind? ..or? transactions?

Comment: Could you explain why you effectively need to shut off every other connection to the DB?

Comment: Could you provide examples of your queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the 2 queries in **SERIALIZABLE** isolation level - it guarantees that the result from the 2 queries is exactly the same as if they were the only 2 queries performed, by locking every record they access, but without locking the rest of the table/tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the innodb storage engine, you could use transaction to realize what you want. Just execute BEGIN before the both queries and COMMIT after them.

Comment: That depends on the isolation level. The default isolation level is: repeatable read, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LOCK TABLE` to prevent other users from updating that table.

**Link**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html